# How to create an argo Workflow from a CronWorkflow, similar to how you can create a kubernetes Job from a CronJob?

Tags: argo-workflows

I can create a `Job` based on a `CronJob` like this:

`kubectl create job --from=cronjob/name-of-my-cron-job name-of-the-manually-triggered-job`

But how can I create a `Workflow` based on a `CronWorkflow` without using the `argo` cmldline program? I only have `kubectl` on the machine where I need to run this.